# Reflecting DLL in Windows Phone API (SIlverlight)

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, reflection

I've got code to read an XAP and reflect a DLL inside.  This works in Silverlight but not in Windows Phone 7.  Is there a way to do this, because AssemblyPart.Load is not in the Windows Phone DLL.

Thanks, code is:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.OpenReadCompleted += delegate(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamResourceInfo resourceInfoDLL = Application.GetResourceStream(
        new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null),
        new Uri("Some.DLL", UriKind.Relative));
       AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
       Assembly assembly = assemblyPart.Load(resourceInfoDLL.Stream);


    .
    .
};

client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("Some.xap", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a XAP is a standard ZIP package, so as long as you can unzip it, you can access its internal contents.

This won't give you much in the long run for the task you are trying to accomplish, because the internal Reflection capabilities are limited to static libraries that are loaded with the application or are accessible from the **GAC (Global Assembly Cache)**. The reasoning is not as much to prevent hacking, because reflecting .NET assemblies won't hurt the OS in most cases (read [this document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/5/93565816-AD4E-4448-B49B-457D07ABB991/Windows%20Phone%207%20Security%20Model_FINAL_122010.pdf) to better understand the security model). It is to prevent dynamic code loading that will perform actions outside the declared capabilities when the application is published.

Comment: Doesn't the Windows Phone architecture prevent the application from using capabilities outside those that are declared?  I think the real reason that `Load` has be been removed from the API is simply to prevent __any__ byte code being delivered from a source other than the marketplace.

Comment: That is exactly the point - "to prevent dynamic code loading"

Comment: Ok, that last sentence in your answer seems to indicate that it would be possible to circumvent the declared capabilities if dynamic dll loading were possible but even it it were my understanding is that the architecture of the phone would prevent such a hypothetical dll from using features that the host app hadn't declared.

Comment: If external DLL loading would be possible, applications could perform activities not specified by the app itself. That means that those activities could potentially block the app from the Marketplace at the approval stage and dynamic code loading would circumvent that.

Comment: Right so we're talking about the more nebulous description of the application than simply whether it uses location services or not?

Comment: Right. Capabilities like location services are tied directly to the declared CAPs, so it would be a bit hard (read: not possible by default) to invoke those if the application itself was not approved to do it.

Answer (score 4):

No, Windows Phone 7 does not support this kind of reflection. You're only allowed to reflect public types, or internal types (ie. from the same assembly). Microsoft don't want people hacking into the functionality that's not directly exposed through a public API.

And ... why would you read a XAP from inside a XAP? That doesn't seem meaningful to me.

Comment: Its possible to include dlls in a xap as content only.  This prevents these dlls from being loaded before the application starts.  The code posted by @Brian can then be used to load subsequent dlls later.  This is often useful where only a few of many dlls are used in a specific instance of the application.  This technique is not available in WP7.  BTW there is no suggestion in the question that any attempt is being made to reflect on types at all let alone private types or member.

Comment: He's using a webclient to download a remote XAP. That first of all doesn't look like something that's likely to be a resource assembly. Secondly, the entire idea doesn't make sense on the Windows Phone ecosystem. Hence, the question to as of why, as there's usually a better answer to provide to these kind of questions.

Comment: I guess it depends on your point of view.  From a technical point of view I can think of many reasons why being able to load dlls dynamically either from the primary application Xap or downloaded xaps "makes sense".  However in a world where we need to prevent malicious behaviour and where revenue streams need to be protected what "makes sense" technically may not "make sense" commercially.  Is that what you are refering when you use the term "ecosystem" ?

Comment: No, I was referring to that loading resources dynamically from another assembly simply doesn't make sense on Windows Phone 7. The phone have it's own resource management system, that's different from Silverlight and WPF. See http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

Comment: I don't see anything in that link that is a) different from silverlight and b) is at all relevant.  The subject under discusion is the ability to dynamically load assemblies into a Windows Phone application.  There are many reasons why we might want to do this in Silverlight hence the reason feature is present.  Many of those reasons are just as valid in a Windows Phone application however commercially such an ability would ultimately be damaging.  That is the __only__ reason I can think of for preventing this feature.

Comment: No. Content and Resource build-actions in WP7 differs from Silverlight. And no, there's no reasons why you would want to load resources from a remotely downloaded DLL in a WP7 application.

Comment: "Content and Resources build-actions in WP7 differs from Silverlight" whilst not relevant I'm curious to know in what way they differ between the platforms (I'm not saying they aren't just that I'm not aware of how they differ, that link you provided indicated no such difference).   If I could download dll resources remotely I could bypass the marketplace marlarky altogether, I could release new modules to an app in a way I control, I could release much smaller Xap to marketplace and then allow the user to configure features they need and don't need dynamically, do I need to go on..?

Comment: And get the worst performing application in history? Dreaming is okay, I prefer sticking to reality. And I strongly doubt that was the OPs original intent. So I'm still curious to as of why he want to do this crazy stunt.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that dlls will always have to be fetched dynamically.  You could store them in isolated storage.  There are many examples of existing WP7 apps that will download and store all sorts of other resources, XML files, images etc.  Why would executable code be any different?  There are good reasons why code is different but they aren't technical ones they are commercial.

Comment: For mobile, you're fetching CONTENT. Not actual parts of the application. Unless you're paranoia and hate your users. And fetching executable code is ALWAYS different.